# How to checkout a single file in GIT

Tags: git

We have developed an auto deployment tool for deploying files(ear,war and jar) in jboss server. Developers will check-in files in  Visual Source safe. The auto deployment tool automatically checkouts latest files one by one specified by developer and deploys it in jboss server by using API. Now we are moving to GIT to maintain our source and other deployment files.

Does  git have an option to check a single file and paths like VSS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692246/git-how-to-undo-changes-of-one-file/692329#692329

Comment: It would have been asked before for sure :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can retrieve a specific file from a Git repository. Something like:

```
git show HEAD:filename.txt
```

If your repository is in another directory, you can use `GIT_DIR`:

```
env GIT_DIR=/path/to/git/repo.git git show HEAD:filename.txt >filename.txt
```

I've shown redirecting the output to a file.

Comment: +1 and to clarify on the "certain previous commit" (instead of HEAD): It refers to the `SHA1 ID` that can easily be found via `gitk`. If I only need to "checkout" that file to a temporary location (i.e. not reverting), then I would use the `show` subcommand: `git show 82e54378856215ef96c5db1ff1160a741b5dcd70:MyProj/proguard/mapping.txt > myproj_mapping.txt`

Answer (score 15):

You can use this

```
git checkout <branch-where-the-file-is> -- path/to/file/in/the/other/branch
```

This will retrieve the file from the other branch, to current