# pull and replace the file that is existing

Tags: git

I want to pull a branch(master branch) to current repository, and replace the file that is existing, not just merge the file, the command `git pull` is not appropriate to my needs, how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you think it isn't appropriate?

`git pull` will update your branch to the same state of the remote repository, so if the file you have is at a newer version on the remote, it will be replaced.

EDIT

If after the pull, merges are done with your local changes, you can reset to the state of remote repository with the following:

```
git reset origin/head -- <file-path>
```

Comment: As you said, but i found my local file be merged with new file from remote repository, not being replaced.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to replace single file you can use this.

```
git checkout -- filename
```

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692329/377342) for more details

Answer (score 2):

So you've made a local commit affecting this file, and wish to discard your commit and just take the remote state without merging, is that right?

Assuming no-one else has seen your local commit (ie, you didn't `push` and nobody `pull`ed from your repo), you can just wind your local HEAD back to before the commit, and then do the pull.

NB. if you're not sure, run `git fetch` first, and then `git status` will tell you whether pull would be a fast-forward or a merge operation.  Fast-forward means your local change is out of the picture.

Comment: No, i just want my local file as same as the remote file in the developing state. Updating local file with remote repository, but sometime, normally, our files is difference between the local and remote, in general, we will merge this two files, but now i want to  totally replace local file with remote, not merge.

Comment: If there is a difference between the local and remote versions of the file, surely that's because you changed it?  Perhaps you can explain the state of the file, in your local `master`, the remote `origin/master` and their common ancestor, a bit more clearly in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It could very well be true that the question-asker actually knows exactly what he's talking about and just needs the mechanical how-tos answered, not a philosophy discussion.

git checkout -- (double dash) then the file name, space between double dash and filename

git checkout -- [file name in repo including path]

example:
git checkout -- views/userEditor.pug

Less philosophy, more actual assistance. Sheesh.