# Overwrite single file in my current branch with the same file in the main branch?

Tags: git

Say I have two branches - `master` and `redesign`.  How would I go about overwriting the file `default.aspx.cs` in my redesign branch with the one from master?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692246/how-do-i-revert-one-file-to-the-last-commit-in-git) but it seems to go over how to revert a file back to it's previous version in the same branch.  I also considered using a `merge`, but I don't want to merge, I want to overwrite.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

`git checkout master path/to/default.aspx.cs`

Before doing this, you probably have to : `git checkout redesign`

So, just **`git checkout FROM_BRANCH_NAME path/to/file`**

Comment: Is there a way to reverse this change with the contents from the original local file?

Comment: With `git checkout` you will overwrite local changes without the possibility to revert those changes. AFAIK. You can try `git show :path/to/file` (with the : prefix). But this assumes, you have staged your file before. See [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememREADMEememmasterREADMEem).

Comment: For me `git checkout origin/master <file>` worked. `master` along didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

To overwrite a file in a branch from another branch, i.e, `master` to `redesign` do (when `redesign` is the current branch)

`git checkout master ./path_to_file/default.aspx.cs`

`git checkout branch_name ./path_to_file/file_name.[file_extension]`

To know more about the command checkout [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) documentation