# Git reset single file in feature branch to be the same as in master/main

Tags: git

I'm trying to revert my changes in a **single file** in my feature branch and I want this file to be the same as in master/main.

I tried:

```
git checkout -- filename
git checkout filename 
git checkout HEAD -- filename
```

It seems that none of these made any changes to my feature branch. Any suggestions?

Comment: As of 2022, there is a cleaner way to do that: `git restore --source HEAD filename`

Comment: For me I wasn't able to use a git command, it would always say file not found. Instead I went to the main branch in my web browser, downloaded the file and replaced the file on my machine. It works as a UI solution in case git isn't working for whatever reason.

Comment: @Adam you wouldn't want to use HEAD there, that will restore the working file to the committed state of the feature branch.  OP wants it to be the same as in master.

I believe your comment on the Accepted answer is the correct way, but your comment I see on the Question here (parallel to this one) should be changed or removed.

Answer (score 1153, accepted):

If you want to revert the file to its state in `master`:

`git checkout origin/master [filename]`

Comment: Thanks Dennan, you are right here. I just found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847425/overwrite-single-file-in-my-current-branch-with-the-same-file-in-the-master-bran. I think this is what I was after.

Comment: I get this repeating error: "Unlink of file '<filename>' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)", then "error: unable to unlink old '<filename>': Invalid argument".

Comment: If you're on windows, keep in mind that git uses CASE SENSITIVE paths. Always screws me up

Comment: `git checkout origin/master [filepath]`

Comment: What's the new 'git restore' equivalent?

Comment: @Marcus That would be `git restore --source origin/master [filename]`

Comment: You saved my life. I have copied the master code over, and my editor have put in millions of whitespaces, that #bitbucket is unable to handle or remove. I know, I know, code should be formatted, but that's a task for another day.

Answer (score 114):

you are almost there; you just need to give the reference to **master**; since you want to get the file from the master branch:

```
git checkout master -- filename
```

Note that the differences will be cached; so if you want to see the differences you obtained; use

```
git diff --cached
```

Comment: What is the utility of using `--` to separate the filename? Is it purely for readability or is there a functional difference?

Comment: @anil https://stackoverflow.com/q/22750028/2082964