# git file still in modified state after reset and checkout from master to feature branch

Tags: git

i want to reset 1 file in my feature branch i did what is suggested from here :
[Git reset single file in feature branch to be the same as in master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972753/git-reset-single-file-in-feature-branch-to-be-the-same-as-in-master)

but when i do git status i still see that is the file is modified in my feature branch
and when i do pull request i still see merage in this file . 
try to do :

```
git reset HEAD include/tools.h
```

and then

```
git push
```

but still is in modified state

$ git status

```
On branch feature/myfix
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/myfix'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   include/tools.h
```

how should i reset this file , i want the master version

Comment: If you want to discard your own work, try following the directions Git printed: `git checkout -- include/tools.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the last commit,

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

To reset(remove current changes) a file,

```
git checkout <file_name>
```

To reset a stagged file,

```
git reset <file_name>
```