# Pull the latest update without stashing the current changes or merging the changes in the file

Tags: git, github

I am git as my control version for my code repository. As I am using multiple computer desktop and laptop.Each time when I try to pull the branch with new changes git give the following message.

```
  error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
       ..../index.php
  Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
  Aborting
```

I do not want to stash the file . So I am deleting the file and doing `git pull`

Any other method is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to simply overwrite your changes in your working tree?

Comment: @greenkeeper : ya I want to overwrite in my working tree

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692246/how-do-i-revert-one-file-to-the-last-commit-in-git I think it is relevant to your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset just one file, as commented by [greenkeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063148/greenkeeper), tou can simply [checkout that file to reset its content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7147320/6309) to what the repo currently holds:

```
git checkout -- index.php
```

If you have multiple files modified locally, and you don't have any work in progress (or it would be lost), you can simply do before pulling:

```
git reset --hard
```

But again, that would reset *all* modified files.