# How to checkout a single file from a local git repository?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a local git repository, and I need to do the equivalent of a TFS 'Undo Pending Changes'. There is no remote repository. There are no branches, just Master. I have tried nearly every suggestion from questions "[How to checkout only one file from git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-checkout-only-one-file-from-git-repository)" and "[Undo working copy modifications of one file in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692246/undo-working-copy-modifications-of-one-file-in-git)". When I do '$ git checkout HEAD -- error.cshtml', I always get "error: pathspec 'error.cshtml' did not match any file(s) known to git." How can I get the latest committed version of a single file from the repository?

Comment: Are you sure the file is actually in the repository? Does `git log --oneline -- error.cshtml` produce any output?

Comment: also check the directory you're executing command

Comment: Is the file in the root of your repo? Of is the file in a  subdir? If the latter, you need to use the full path from the dir you execute the command: `git checkout HEAD -- path/to/error.cshtml`.

Comment: That was it @Waylan, the file was a few subdirs down. I thought checkout would recurse through the repo. Thank you.