# Git how to revert staged /unstaged modified file

Tags: git, github, version-control

In Git(2.16). Suppose, I modified a single file and did not stage yet I would like to revert the file back to original? Also, how can I accomplish this on a staged file?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo working copy modifications of one file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692246/undo-working-copy-modifications-of-one-file-in-git)

Answer (score 6):

`git reset HEAD fileName` will unstage the file in staging directory, but the changes will still be present in your working directory. Now, if you want the original copy of the file, you can use -

```
git checkout fileName
```

Answer (score 2):

`git reset HEAD` unstages all the staged files.

`git checkout .` discards all the unstaged changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below command to revert modified files (both for staged and unstaged) as original:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

For undoing changes in the unstaged state for all files

```
$ git restore .
```

For undoing changes in the unstaged state for a single file

```
$ git restore chapter1.txt
```

For unstaging the changes in staged state for all files

```
$ git reset
$ git reset head
```

For unstaging the changes in staged state for a single

```
$ git reset songs.txt
```

For undoing changes in the unstaged & staged state for all files

```
$ git reset --hard
$ git checkout head .
```

For undoing changes in the unstaged & staged state for a single file

```
$ git checkout head chapter1.txt
```

There are lots of other ways of accomplishing these tasks too.

But, these causes confusions.

I prefer this structure and commands.