# Git - how to get the local changes instead of the remote

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm new with git, and I made some changes to my script, committed and pushed them to my bitbucket account. When I tried to Upload the newer script version to the server, I got the following error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
web_app.py
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Can anyone tell me how to run-down the version on the server, and get the version I fixed on my bitbucket?

So far I've tried:`git reset myfile.py`
and then `git pull` but, I got the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Remove local modifications

You want `git checkout .` to remove local modifications and `git pull` to pull down the new modifications.

Be aware that this will remove **all** local modifications, so check this if you want to just do 1 file:

[Undo working copy modifications of one file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692246/undo-working-copy-modifications-of-one-file-in-git)

### Save and re-apply local modifications

If you want to save the local modifications, but pull down the changes you can do:

```
git stash save // To save the local mods in the stash
git pull // To pull down remote mods
git stash pop // To put back the local modifications
```

Be aware that if you have changed the same lines in the file you may need to resolve conflicts.