# Merging directory changes when projects have continued

Tags: git

I have created a branch from master to bring a lot of C# projects into one. However, some of the other projects in the repository have continued development, but have been moved. I'll try and give an example:

My repository contains:

- Project A
- Project B
- Project C
- Project D
- Project E

I have rearranged the repository into directories:

- Directory 1

  - Project A
  - Project B
  - Project C
- Directory 2

  - Project D
  - Project E

I've been making changes on project A, B, and C, and when I merge these will be fine. However, projects D and E have continued development merged into master branch, so my copies of them are out of date.

How do I merge these changes into master in a way that keeps the newest development on projects D and E, but also moves them into these directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood, the easiest way might be just fetching the changes from the repository and checkout only for the updated files (D and E in your example), then commit your changes of reorganizing folder structure with the new files.

To checkout only certain files, check the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692246/undo-working-copy-modifications-of-one-file-in-git) question